# Excel Numerical Wildacard

Tags: excel, formula, numeric

I'm sure this should be simple but I can't figure this out.

Is there a way to search for a partial match in a list of numbers, numerics only.

In the example below I subtract the start time from the finish time to get the hours worked minus 1 hour for lunch. I'd like to convert the .3 for half hours to .5 for accurate calculations so came up with this formula, =IF(E2=*.3,E2+0.2,E2) but excel keeps changing my formula to =IF(E2=0.3,E2+0.2,E2)

This formula seems to only work if I make the value of E (hours column) 0.3 by typing it in manually, getting the same value of 0.3 from the calculation doesn't seem to trigger the IF statement.

```
Date        Day         Start   Finish  Hours -1  Appox Days Pay
20/04/17    Thursday    08.00   17.00   8         £60.80
28/04/17    Friday      08.00   18.30   9.3       £70.68
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your requirement, something like this formula should work for you (make sure to format the cell as `General` instead of `Time`):

```
=TIME(INT(E2),MOD(E2,1)*100,0)*24
```

This will convert the decimal portion to the desired fraction.

For example, 9.3 = 9:30, and the result of this formula will be 9.5 for 9 and 1/2 hours.

Another example, 8.45 = 8:45, and the result of this formula will be 8.75 for 8 and 3/4 hours.

It will also keep plain old 8 as an 8 (for 8 hours and 0 minutes)

Comment: Nice use of `Mod()` and `Time()` :D  I didn't think to try that, instead was more focused on the formatting "issue"...

Comment: Thanks for the edit to the original post, and thanks for the solution it worked a treat.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue is with how Excel is interpreting your data.  May I suggest another idea?

Format your Start/Finish/Hours - 1 columns to this custom format: `0":"00`.

Then, for your times, use `800` for `08.00`, `1700` for `17.00`, etc.

Then for your hours, use the formula: `=D2-C2-100` (`100` being 1 hour).  That should get you what you are looking for.

[image]

Then you can adjust your calculation for payment as needed.

Comment: Thank you bruce for your input, I did trial your system but I found the approx days pay, which is calculated automatically, was a long way out of range, so I opted for Tigers solution

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the number to text first and then use the FIND function to check if the ".3" exists in the number. If it does not exist it will bring an VALUE error, which can be bypassed using the IFERROR function. For your purpose, the following will return 9.5 if E2 contains 9.3:

```
=IF(IFERROR(FIND(".3",TEXT(E2,"0.00")),0)<>0,E2+0.2,E2)
```

You can try using wildcards within the FIND function. I have no idea on how to use those.

Comment: Thanks for replying when I have a little more time I'll explore you solution as it might well come in handy